# Puling 90,000 emails to Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, gmail

I have used https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/160232/gmail-bulk-emails-manipulation and modified a bit to copy some 90,000 emails (from a free gmail account) to a sheet.

The script is working only once. After one cycle, the trigger becomes "disabled" with "Unknown reason".

I reduced the batch size, increased the time gap, but still it is getting the same error.

Where am I going wrong?

```
/**
 * Creates the first trigger to call batchArchiveEmail. 
 */
function init(){

    var Triggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
    for (var p = 0; p < Triggers.length; p++) {
      ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(Triggers[p])
    }



   ScriptApp
    .newTrigger('batchArchiveEmail')
    .timeBased()
    .after(60 * 1000)
    .create();
    console.log(`trigger created`)
}

/**
 * Archive emails by batches preventing controlling limiting the execution time and  
 * creating a trigger if there are still threads pending to be archived.
 */ 
function batchArchiveEmail(){
  const start = Date.now();
  /** 
   * Own execution time limit for the search and archiving operations to prevent an 
   * uncatchable error. As the execution time check is done in do..while condition there  
   * should be enough time to one search and archive operation and to create a trigger 
   * to start a new execution. 
   */ 
  const maxTime = 3 * 60 * 1000; // Instead of 25 use 3 for Google free accounts
  const batchSize = 50;
  let threads, elapsedTime;
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet=ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  /** Search and archive threads, then repeat until the search returns 0 threads or the 
   * maxTime is reached
   */ 
  var ms=[];
  do {

    threads = GmailApp.search('label:inbox before:2022/5/1');
    for (let j = 0; j < threads.length; j += batchSize) {
      //below code added by me
      ms=[];
      var messages = threads[j].getMessages();
      for (var m = 0; m < messages.length; m++) {
        var from = messages[m].getFrom(); //from field
        var mId = messages[m].getId();//id field to create the link later
        var supportStats = [];
        var to = messages[m].getTo();//to field
        var time = messages[m].getDate();//date field
        var subject = messages[m].getSubject();//subject field
        var body=messages[m].getPlainBody();
        var tel=[];
        tel = body.match(/[\+]?\d{10}|\(\d{3}\)\s?-\d{6}|\d{3}\s-\d{3}\s\d{4}/);
        supportStats.push(from);
        supportStats.push(to);
        supportStats.push(time);
        supportStats.push(subject);
        supportStats.push('https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox/'+mId); //build the URL to the email
        supportStats.push(body);
        if (tel){supportStats.push(tel[0])} else {supportStats.push("")};
        ms.push(supportStats);
      }
    var lr=sheet.getLastRow();
    sheet.getRange(lr+1,1,ms.length,7).setValues(ms);
    //above code added by me
    GmailApp.moveThreadsToArchive(threads.slice(j, j + batchSize));
    };
    /**
     * Used to prevent to have too many calls in a short time, might not be 
     * necessary with a large enough batchSize
     */
    Utilities.sleep(`2000`); 
    elapsedTime = Date.now() - start;
  } while (threads.length > 0 &&  elapsedTime < maxTime);
  if(threads.length > 0){
    /** Delete the last trigger */

    var Triggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
    for (var p = 0; p < Triggers.length; p++) {
      ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(Triggers[p])
    }


    //deleteTriggers();

    /** Create a one-time new trigger */
    ScriptApp
    .newTrigger('batchArchiveEmail')
    .timeBased()
    .after(300 * 1000)
    .create();
    console.log(`next trigger created`)
  } else {
    /** Delete the last trigger */
    var Triggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
    for (var p = 0; p < Triggers.length; p++) {
      ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(Triggers[p])
    }
    console.log(`No more threads to process`);
  }
}
```

Comment: Not reproducible on my side. Have to say that I've been unable to test it with 90.000 mails. What happens when you run the function `batchArchiveEmail`? From what I understand the issue happens when you run the init func, right?

Comment: The init function runs. A trigger is created. That function runs after one minute. It works. That trigger is deleted. A new trigger is created to run after 5 minutes. This trigger is getting disabled due to unknown reasons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue of `This trigger has been disable for an unknown reason` is reported [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/150756612), and seems to be related to the `V8 runtime`. Click on the `+1` to let Google know that you are also affected by the issue.

Deactivating the `Project Settings > General Settings > Enable Chrome V8 runtime` seems to fix the issue for some users. Same as changing the `appsscript.json` key `runtimeVersion` from:

```json
  "runtimeVersion": "V8"
```

to

```json
  "runtimeVersion": "DEPRECATED_ES5"
```

Comment: I disabled the V8 and the trigger has executed 4 times successfully. Thank you

Comment: It worked for some 20 cycles and stopped with an error "Service invoked too many times for one day: gmail.  at batchArchiveEmail(Code:144)". It was able to pull 916 messages into the google sheet. But, I think, it has nothing to do with the code or logic. Is there a way I can pull more mails into the sheet?

Answer (score 2):

### Issue and workaround:

When I tested your script, I confirmed the same situation with you. In this case, unfortunately, even when the next trigger time is increased, the issue couldn't be avoided.

In this answer, I would like to introduce a workaround that I have already posted at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72341605/7108653). Unfortunately, my answer was not useful for that thread. But, fortunately, when I tested your script, I confirmed that this workaround can be used.

About `The newTrigger is never running.`, if you are using V8 runtime at the script editor and the installed trigger doesn't work, I'm worried that this might be the bug. [Ref1](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/150756612) [Ref2](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/142405165)

But, fortunately, in the current stage, there is a workaround for removing this bug. It's to use Web Apps. [Ref](https://tanaikech.github.io/2021/09/22/executing-function-with-minutes-timer-in-specific-times-using-google-apps-script/) I had had the same situation before. The flow of this workaround is as follows.

1. Run the script you want to run.
2. When the time-driven trigger is installed, that is installed using the Web Apps.

   - This is the important point.

In this case, the time-driven trigger installed by the script is run. By this workaround, your script works with enabling V8 runtime. When your script is modified, it becomes as follows.

### Usage:

In this workaround, Web Apps is used. So, please do the following flow.

#### 1. Deploy Web Apps.

1. On the script editor, at the top right of the script editor, please click "click Deploy" -> "New deployment".
2. Please click "Select type" -> "Web App".
3. Please input the information about the Web App in the fields under "Deployment configuration".
4. Please select **"Me"** for **"Execute as"**.
5. Please select **"Only myself"** for **"Who has access"**.
6. Please click "Deploy" button. And, click "Done" button.
7. On the script editor, at the top right of the script editor, please click "click Deploy" -> "Test deployments".
8. Please copy the URL of Web Apps.

   - In this case, the URL is like `https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/dev`.

The detailed information can be seen at [the official document](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#deploy_a_script_as_a_web_app) and [my report](https://github.com/tanaikech/taking-advantage-of-Web-Apps-with-google-apps-script).

#### 2. Modified script.

Please modify your script as follows. Please set your Web Apps URL to `webAppsUrl`.

```js
const functionName = "batchArchiveEmail"; // This is the function name for executing.
const webAppsUrl = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/dev"; // Please set your Web Apps URL.

// When v8 runtime is used, when the trigger is set from the function executing by a trigger, the trigger is disabled. This is the recognized bug. But unfortunately, this has still not been resolved. (September 21, 2021)
// https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/150756612
// https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/142405165
const doGet = _ => {
  deleteTriggers();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger(functionName).timeBased().after(60000).create();
  return ContentService.createTextOutput();

  // DriveApp.getFiles(); // This is used for automatically detecting the scopes for requesting to Web Apps. Please don't remove this comment line.
};

const deleteTriggers = _ => {
  ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers().forEach(e => {
    if (e.getHandlerFunction() == functionName) {
      ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(e);
    }
  });
}

// Please run this function.
function init() {
  deleteTriggers();
  UrlFetchApp.fetch(webAppsUrl, { headers: { authorization: "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() } });
  console.log(`trigger created`)
}

/**
 * Archive emails by batches preventing controlling limiting the execution time and  
 * creating a trigger if there are still threads pending to be archived.
 */
function batchArchiveEmail() {
  const start = Date.now();
  /** 
   * Own execution time limit for the search and archiving operations to prevent an 
   * uncatchable error. As the execution time check is done in do..while condition there  
   * should be enough time to one search and archive operation and to create a trigger 
   * to start a new execution. 
   */ 
  const maxTime = 3 * 60 * 1000; // Instead of 25 use 3 for Google free accounts
  const batchSize = 50;
  let threads, elapsedTime;
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet=ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  /** Search and archive threads, then repeat until the search returns 0 threads or the 
   * maxTime is reached
   */ 
  var ms=[];
  do {

    threads = GmailApp.search('label:inbox before:2022/5/1');
    for (let j = 0; j < threads.length; j += batchSize) {
      //below code added by me
      ms=[];
      var messages = threads[j].getMessages();
      for (var m = 0; m < messages.length; m++) {
        var from = messages[m].getFrom(); //from field
        var mId = messages[m].getId();//id field to create the link later
        var supportStats = [];
        var to = messages[m].getTo();//to field
        var time = messages[m].getDate();//date field
        var subject = messages[m].getSubject();//subject field
        var body=messages[m].getPlainBody();
        var tel=[];
        tel = body.match(/[\+]?\d{10}|\(\d{3}\)\s?-\d{6}|\d{3}\s-\d{3}\s\d{4}/);
        supportStats.push(from);
        supportStats.push(to);
        supportStats.push(time);
        supportStats.push(subject);
        supportStats.push('https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox/'+mId); //build the URL to the email
        supportStats.push(body);
        if (tel){supportStats.push(tel[0])} else {supportStats.push("")};
        ms.push(supportStats);
      }
    var lr=sheet.getLastRow();
    sheet.getRange(lr+1,1,ms.length,7).setValues(ms);
    //above code added by me
    GmailApp.moveThreadsToArchive(threads.slice(j, j + batchSize));
    };
    /**
     * Used to prevent to have too many calls in a short time, might not be 
     * necessary with a large enough batchSize
     */
    Utilities.sleep(2000); 
    elapsedTime = Date.now() - start;
  } while (threads.length > 0 &&  elapsedTime < maxTime);

  if (threads.length > 0) {
    /** Delete the last trigger */
    deleteTriggers();

    /** Create a one-time new trigger */
    UrlFetchApp.fetch(webAppsUrl, { headers: { authorization: "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() } });
    console.log(`next trigger created`)
  } else {
    /** Delete the last trigger */
    deleteTriggers();
    console.log(`No more threads to process`);
  }
}
```

#### 3. Testing.

In the modified script, as the 1st run, please run `init()` with the script editor. By this, your script is run and install the time-driven trigger with Web Apps. And, the installed trigger is run automatically by the time-driven trigger.

### Note:

- In this modified script, it supposes that your function `batchArchiveEmail()` works fine. Please be careful about this.
- If you disable the V8 runtime, I thought that the script might be worked without the above modification. But in that case, the process cost of the loop will become high. [Ref](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/3331e1e631d619abef8f32c4be14ba3a) By this, I would like to introduce this workaround.

### Reference:

- [Executing Function with Minutes timer in Specific Times using Google Apps Script](https://tanaikech.github.io/2021/09/22/executing-function-with-minutes-timer-in-specific-times-using-google-apps-script/)

Comment: @Rubén In this situation, when I tested the OP's script, even when the wait time is increased, the next time-driven trigger created by a script running the trigger couldn't be run. But, I couldn't find the difference between this OP's script and this script in https://stackoverflow.com/q/72341605 . So, I proposed a workaround I had posted at https://stackoverflow.com/q/72341605 that might be able to be used. In this case, I confirmed this workaround can be used. Have you ever had the same situation? I thought that if the reason for this was found, it will be useful for other users.

Comment: Hi Tanaike. Taking a quick look into the the OP's code I saw some problems that might be causing the script to fail ... i.e. the data type of the parameter used for Utilities.sleep is wrong, (it's a string instead of a number). I'll  return a bit later .

Comment: @Rubén Thank you for replying. I had thought the same point of ``Utilities.sleep(`2000`);``. But, if my test method was correct, even when I modified it to `Utilities.sleep(2000);`, the issue couldn't be removed. In my proposed modified script, that is modified. Now, I continue to be looking for the reason for this issue. Unfortunately, I cannot still obtain it.

Comment: Tanaike: I was able to run successfully the code from the OP (instead of adding the body I'm adding an empty string and commented out the line that archives the emails).

Comment: I forgot to mention that I also changed `label:inbox` to `in:inbox`. I just added what I mentioned in this and the previous comment in an answer.

Comment: @Rubén Thank you for the discussions. About `I was able to run successfully the code from the OP`, in my test, unfortunately, I confirmed that even when `Utilities.sleep` as a worker in order to suppose the OP's script works is used instead of the OP's script, the same issue occurred. When I had tested [the script of this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72341605), I confirmed the issue was removed. So, I thought that in the case of this question, the situation might be different, while I cannot find it.

Comment: @Rubén But, I believe that these discussions will be useful for not only us but also for other users.

Comment: Hi Tanaike. I deleted my original answer and posted a new one. Tl;Dr From [comment #199](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/150756612#comment119), dated Jun 7, 2022 06:49AM CDT, 

> Hi,
>
> To anyone affected by this, can you provide an affected script id?

Comment: @Rubén Thank you for replying. About `I deleted my original answer and posted a new one. Tl;Dr From comment #199, dated Jun 7, 2022 06:49AM CDT, > Hi, > > To anyone affected by this, can you provide an affected script id?`, I think that the reason for this issue is due to that the endpoint retrieved by `ScriptApp.getService().getUrl()` has been changed.

Comment: @Rubén After V8 runtime was released, this returned the endpoint like `https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/dev`. But, now, it returns `https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/exec`. But, the endpoint cannot be used. When I checked the deployment ID, such the deployment ID cannot be found. I think that this might be a bug. So, in my answer, I showed `const webAppsUrl = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/dev";` for directly setting. When the endpoint of Web Apps is directly given, the script works.

Answer (score 0):

I tested the code in the question with a slight change b/c I don't want to archive all the messages in my inbox. It worked correctly.

The change was just adding a more specific search query on `threads = GmailApp.search('label:inbox before:2022/5/1');`. The change looks as follow:

```
threads = GmailApp.search(`label:inbox before:2022/5/1 from:"Sender Display Name"`);
```

where `"Sender Display Name"` is the display name of newsletter that I get on my primary category.

Considering the other answers (at the time of writing this, [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72562166/1595451) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72568293/1595451)) in this question as well other related questions here and posts from other places, it looks that there is something failing on Google, perhaps it's something affecting few projects / users. From [comment #199](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/150756612#comment119), dated Jun 7, 2022 06:49AM CDT,

> Hi,
>
> To anyone affected by this, can you provide an affected script id?